# How to create a temp database for my app in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, directory, temp

I have a database for my application which will be installed/created during the first run of the application. This database is located in its default place i.e. `/data/data/<package_name>/databases`.

Now I want to create a temp database apart from the above in different folder say

```
/data/data/<package_name>/temp
```

Is it possible? If yes, can I get a code example for the same? If no, is there any other way, apart from creating the temp database in `/data/data/<package_name>/databases`?

Comment: this might help: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I want to do it programmatically as the data is coming from internet

Answer (score 0):

I'd just pull the old database from the emulator with DDMS or ADB and upload again in /data/data/temp and change your code to access the new temp database.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically as the data is coming from internet